# How to prove a set of solution of a continuous function is closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

E.g. if the set is $S=\{(x,y), g(x,y) = 0\}$, $g$ is a continuous function. How to prove that S is closed?

It seems that the relationship between continuous function and convergent sequence and the Lemma that "A set A in a metric space is closed iff the limit of every convergent
sequence in A belongs to A" can be used here. I am not sure how the relationship between continuous function and convergent sequence is applicable here.

Comment: As you can see from the different kind of answers the argument is depending on your definition of a continuous function. It would be helpful to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a general metric space, let $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a real continuous function and let $A=g^{-1}(0)$. Choose a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $A$. Then by continuity
$$
g\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g\left(x_n\right).
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: How do you know that a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ exist in $A$?

Comment: Let $x\in A$. Then the sequence $(x,x,x,\ldots)$ is a convergent sequence for example.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could just note that $\{0\}$ is a closed set.   Hence $S=g^{-1}(0)$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Take $(x,y)\in S^c$, then $g(x,y)\neq 0$,  say $ g(x,y) = a>0$ (if $ g(x,y) = a<0$  we can do similar things). Then take b,c real number such that $0<b<a<c$. Since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}[(b,c)]$ must be open. And we can easly see that $(x,y)\in g^{-1}[(b,c)] \subset S^c$. So $S^c$ is open then $S$ is closed.